# Selecting HTML elements by mousemove angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to implement something like ngSelectable . But the difference being I want the selection to start from outside the li element .

I have also looked angular-multiple-select but it does not work out because the selection disappears on mousedown event .

[ngSelectable](https://github.com/willgm/ngSelectable)
[Angular Multiple Selection](https://github.com/maxazan/angular-multiple-selection)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question..
If you want to select an element using an event such as `mousemove`, you should register to it on the element. If you want to catch the event from outside the element, you should register to it on the parent element, or possibly even the `window` object (or `$window` in angular), depending on your need.